# Cake pattern with overriding abstract type don't work with Upper Type Bounds

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, traits, cake-pattern

I want to override abstract type in trait with `<:` and not with `=` (like answer here [Scala Upper Bounds : value is not a member of type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217918/scala-upper-bounds-value-is-not-a-member-of-type-parameter)).

I want to use cake pattern, but this doesn't work, i don't understand why ?

```
trait A {
  def ping = println("ping")
}

trait Cake {
  type T
}

trait S { this: Cake =>
  type T = A
  def t: T
  t.ping
}
```

OK, this example run, but in my real use case i want to override type with `<:` and not with `=` .It seems impossible to access the t function, why ?

```
trait S { this: Cake =>
  type T <: A
  def t: T
  t.ping
}
```

return an error `value ping is not a member of S.this.T`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a shortcoming of Scala's type system. When determining the members in a mixin, Scala uses two rules: First, concrete always overrides abstract. Second, If two members are both concrete, or both abstract, then the one that comes later in linearization order wins.

Furthermore, the self type of a trait

```
trait S { this: C => ... }
```

is implicitly augmented to

```
trait S { this: S with C => ... }
```

so that definitions in the trait S can be accessed within S. In your case, the trait S is seen as:

```
trait S { this: S with Cake =>
  type T = A
  def t: T
  t.ping
}
```

Now, as long as T is concrete this is fine because it overrides the abstract T in Cake. But if T is abstract, the one in Cake cames later in the linearization order and wins. And that T does not have an upper bound, so no member ping. One way to fix this is to change the linearization order by writing:

```
trait S { this: Cake with S =>
  type T <: A
  def t: T
  t.ping
}
```

It would be cleaner if Scala had a different rule that says that all constraints of abstract type members are merged in the mixin, instead of picking a single member according to linearization order. That's a change we want to consider in the future, but we need to be careful with backwards compatibility.