# Ambiguous reference to overloaded definition with inherited inner class, scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, overloading, inner-classes, ambiguous-call

So here is the problematic code:

```
trait World {
  type State
  def dynamics(s: State): State
  // ...
}
trait GridWorld extends World {
  class State {...} // concrete
  def dynamics(s: State) = s    // concrete
  // some other staff still abstract
}
trait SimpleGridWorld extends GridWorld {
  class State extends super.State {...}  // concrete
  def foo {dynamics(new State)}  // compiler error
}
```

The compiler says that, `dynamics` in both `World` and `GridWorld` match the signature. However, in `World` it is abstract and then implemented in `GridWorld`, so it seems to me that it is clear that I am calling `GridWorld.this.dynamics`.

Another thing I noticed is that, if I remove the `extends super.State` in `SimpleGridWorld`, everything works fine (which I don't understand why, and I do need the functionalities defined in `GridWorld.State` here). Any explanations? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Anyway I am seeing my design pattern quite weird, since if `State` in `SimpleGridWorld` does not inherit `GridWorld.this.State`, `dynamics` would refer to the unimplemented one defined in the root trait `World` (which makes sense because the implementation in `GridWorld` may use the functionalities of `GridWorld.this.State` which may not exist in `SimpleGridWorld.this.State`). But what I want is:

1. `XXXWorld.this.State` must inherit its `super.State` (or just use it)
2. `dynamics` always refers to `super.dynamics` if implemented in the super trait/class unless overrided here.

How can I do this? I think it is not a totally irrelevant question, and probably the answer to the previous one would tell me how to redesign my pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
trait World {
  type State
  def dynamics(s: State): State
}
trait GridWorld extends World {
  type State = MyState
  class MyState {} // concrete
  def dynamics(s: State) = s    // concrete
}
trait SimpleGridWorld extends GridWorld {
  class MyState extends super.MyState {}  // concrete
  def foo {dynamics(new MyState)}  // compiler error; ok
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but why still compiler error? I tried it and it seems working, despite that I don't think `MyState` and `State` should ever have separate meanings conceptually.

Comment: Hmm, I think about it more and find that there is something thoughtful in your solution. `GridWorld` is very special in the type hierarchy as from there, subclasses no longer have `State==MyState`. This makes some sense because `GridWorld` is the place where `dynamics` is implemented. As long as I do not override `dynamics` in later classes (which I thought of but maybe should not do so), everything works fine and is meaningful.

Comment: you might want to consider something similar to this [Tour of Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124) article and use `type State <: StateIf` and then define an interface bass class `abstract class StateIf`

Comment: This is one of my favorites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213395/cake-pattern-with-overriding-abstract-type-dont-work-with-upper-type-bounds