# How can I remove this extra type parameter?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance

I currently have:

```
class X[+T: Numeric](val x: T)
abstract class M[N: Numeric, T <: X[N]] { // <- I'd like to remove N.
  def apply(x: Int): T
  final def row = (1 to 10).map(this(_))
}
```

I use it like this:

```
class Y(x: Double, val y: Double) extends X[Double](x)
class Z extends M[Double, Y] {           // <- So that this is simpler.
  def apply(x: Int) = new Y(0.0, 0.0)
}
```

It works like this:

```
object testapp {
  // row is properly polymorphic, allowing access to Y.y
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = (new Z).row.map(r => println(r.y))
}
```

I want `Z` to be simpler so that I can use `M` like:

```
class Z extends M[Y] {
  def apply(x: Int) = new Y(0.0, 0.0)
}
```

or, even better:

```
class Z extends M[Double] {           // i.e. Meaning apply can return
  def apply(x: Int) = new Y(0.0, 0.0) // any subclass of X[Double]
}
```

[Here are my Gist iterations](https://gist.github.com/4301540) to reach this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third way in type params vs type members is to use both.

An advantage of a type member is that it doesn't pollute the signature of child classes.  The type member can remain abstract if it is superfluous (even in a concrete class); and only the bottom class must define it if necessary.

```
  import scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq
  class X[+T: Numeric](val x: T)
  abstract class M[+A: Numeric] {
    type W <: X[A]
    def apply(x: Int): W
    final def row: IndexedSeq[W] = (1 to 10) map apply
    def sumx: A = {  // in terms of the underlying Numeric
      val n = implicitly[Numeric[A]]
      n fromInt (0 /: row)((s,w) => s + (n toInt w.x))
    }
  }

  class Y(x: Double, val y: Double) extends X[Double](x)
  class Z extends M[Double] {
    type W = Y
    def apply(x: Int) = new Y(0.0, 0.0)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = (new Z).row foreach (Console println _.y)
```

Comment: Chosen since answered the question most directly. Thanks. Can you clarify for me? I am reading it as : `type W <: X[A]` defines a type `W` within `M` such that `W` is a subtype of `X[A]`. Then in subtypes of `M`, `W` is "overriden" to be the type needed by the subtype of `M`?

Comment: With the bound, type W is still abstract, so no override is required when you define it.  (Like any other member.) (Spec 4.3.  Also, beware http://stackoverflow.com/a/10223364/1296806.)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really need `class M` here:

```
class X[+T: Numeric](val x: T)
def row[W <: X[_]](c: => Int => W) = (1 to 10).map(c)

class Y(x: Double, val y: Double) extends X[Double](x)
def z = row(_ => new Y(0.0, 0.0))

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = z.map(r => println(r.y))
```

If you want to keep `M`, you use same idea:

```
class X[+T: Numeric](val x: T)
abstract class M[W <: X[_]] {
    def apply(x: Int): W
    final def row = (1 to 10).map(this(_))
}

class Y(x: Double, val y: Double) extends X[Double](x)
class Z extends M[Y] {
  def apply(x: Int) = new Y(0.0, 0.0)
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = (new Z).row.map(r => println(r.y))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the goal isn't to eliminate `M`. I think I need it (but i'm considering your alternative). It's part of a larger solution. The idea is that `M` is a collection that can only contain types bounded by `X[T]` where `T` is `Numeric`. I create several subclasses of `M` to encapsulate different functionality against the elements.

Comment: Instead of several subclasses you can create several functions like z. I can miss something without knowledge of larger solution, but I think OO encapsulation is overhead here.

Comment: The problem I have with the function-approach is that `M` is actually a type, specifically, a collection. But i think you might be right that i should provide functions that operate on the single parameterized type `M` rather than subclassing `M`. One problem with your answer is `X[_]`. `_` is `Any` but i need `Numeric`.

Comment: It will not compile with X[T] that have not implementation for Numeric typeclass in scope. Check it with 'class StringX(x: String) extends X[String](x)'