# this.type incorrectly compiled?

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

When porting my [project](http://subscript-lang.org) from Scala 2.10 to 2.11 I got a sudden compilation error with type parametrization. I tried to modify and pinpoint; still something strange went wrong. Could someone explain?
BTW I was happy with this regression (or progression), since it motivated me to simplify the code.

```
trait TNode {type N <:  Node {type T = this.type}}
trait  Node {type T <: TNode {type N = this.type}; def t: T}

trait TNodeCode[R] extends TNode {type N <:  NodeCode[R]; val code: ()=>N=>R}
trait  NodeCode[R] extends  Node {type T <: TNodeCode[R]}

object Test {
  def executeCode[R](n: Node, code: =>()=>R): R = {null.asInstanceOf[R]}

  def executeTCode[N <: NodeCode[R], R](n: N): R = {
    executeCode(n, ()=>n.t.code.apply.apply(n))
    // compile error:                       ^
    //   type mismatch; found: n.type (with underlying type N) required: _1.N where val _1: n.T
  }
}
```

Comment: I love the columnar alignment! But you squashed out the spaces around some of the punctuation.

Comment: Don't you need to put `()` after the first `apply` on the line starting with `executeCode(n, ...`?

Comment: Thanks; I improved the spacing a little. The first `apply` works with and without the empty parameter list `()`.

Comment: this is unrelated, but your `T <: TNodeCode[R]` type parameter for `executeTCode` is not needed: it isn't used, and there is nothing to infer it from anyway (not referenced in arguments or return type).

Comment: Thank you; I removed it
(was: `def executeTCode[N<:NodeCode[R], T<:TNodeCode[R], R](n: N): R`)

Answer (score 1):

I have a hasty partial answer:

When you change the bound on `T` in `NodeCode`, you lose the information that the previous bound was a refinement with `N` tied to `this.type`.

The last bound wins.

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10213395/1296806) I was thinking of.

This may not suit your needs:

```
trait TNode0 {type N <:  Node0 }
trait  Node0 {type T <: TNode0 ; def t: T}

trait TNode extends TNode0 {type N <:  Node {type T = this.type}}
trait  Node extends Node0  {type T <: TNode {type N = this.type}}

trait TNodeCode[R] extends TNode0 {type N <:  NodeCode[R] {type T = this.type}; val code: ()=>N=>R}
trait  NodeCode[R] extends  Node0 {type T <: TNodeCode[R] {type N = this.type}}
```

Edit: that doesn't seem to help, sorry.  Something else is going on.