# What's the difference between `trait Y { this: X => }` and `trait Y extends X {}`

Tags: scala, traits

Scala code:

```
trait X

trait Y1 {
  this: X => 
}

trait Y2 extends X {
}
```

I wonder what's the difference between `Y1` and `Y2` traits? If I have a class `Z` need to extend `Y`:

```
class Z1 extend Y1 with X

class Z2 extends Y2
```

It seems there is no difference for the two classes `Z1` and `Z2`. If they are nearly the same, which style would you recommend?

Comment: Major difference for me is in scalac errors. In case of self dependence they are much more cryptic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you're in a deeply nested scope, and the alias is useful for the outer object, for instance [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L55).

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10223364/1296806), the linearizations of the two types for `this` are inverted.

That is, you have `this: Y with X` and `this: X with Y`.

`this` matters (pun intended):

```
scala> trait X { type T }
defined trait X

scala> trait Y { type T <: String ; def t: T ; def f = t.length }
defined trait Y

scala> trait Y { this: X => type T <: String ; def t: T ; def f = t.length }
<console>:8: error: value length is not a member of Y.this.T
       trait Y { this: X => type T <: String ; def t: T ; def f = t.length }
                                                                    ^

scala> trait Y { this: X with Y => type T <: String ; def t: T ; def f = t.length }
defined trait Y

scala> trait Y extends X { type T <: String ; def t: T ; def f = t.length }
defined trait Y
```

But as the linked, authoritative answer says, it may not matter forever.

Answer (score 1):

`trait B extends A` means that B *is* an A.

`trait B { this: A => }` is dependency injection - you want B to *require* A.

Consider these two REPL sessions:

```
> trait A
defined trait A

> trait B extends A
defined trait B

> class C
defined class C

> new C with A
res0: C with A = $anon$1@706abf59

> new C with B
res1: C with B = $anon$1@2004aa19
```

And this:

```
> trait A
defined trait A

> trait B { this : A => }
defined trait B

> class C
defined class C

> new C with A
res0: C with A = $anon$1@1ef535db

> new C with B
<console>:11: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type C with B does not conform to B's selftype B with A
          new C with B
                     ^
```

Comment: Also I just came across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses) - the accepted answer does a much better job of explaining this than I did.