# Scala: overriding type member with bounds

Tags: scala, types, mixins, traits, type-bounds

I've narrowed down my issue to the following minimal (non-)working example:

```
class Z
trait A[E <: Z] { type T[X <: E] <: A[X] }
trait B[E <: Z] extends A[E] { type T[X <: E] <: B[X] }
trait C[E <: Z, F[X <: Z] <: C[X, F]] extends A[E] { type T[X <: E] = F[X] }
class D[E <: Z] extends B[E] with C[E, D]
```

It is sort of a higher-kinded F-bounded polymorphism (I'm using T[E] as the return value of some methods). When I try to compile this code I get:

```
error: overriding type T in trait B with bounds[X <: E] <: B[X];
 type T in trait C, which equals [X <: E]D[X] has incompatible type
```

However, given that `D` is a sub-type of `B` and that the same `E` is passed to `B` and `C`, the types shouldn't be incompatible. Martin Odersky explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213395/cake-pattern-with-overriding-abstract-type-dont-work-with-upper-type-bounds) that when merging a member in a mixin, there are two rules: 1) concrete over abstract and 2) linearisation order. In this case both are "concrete" types so we go with 2). But the linearisation order says that `C` should win over `B`, so I'm left wondering what is it that I'm getting wrong here.

Comment: I'm hesitant to say this is a Scala bug, but it seems like something weird is going on here. You can reproduce the problem with lesser code if you remove the extra type parameter from `C`. Strangely, if you change `<: E` to `<: Z`, the error is gone. So perhaps there is something wrong with the `E` floating between `X` and `Z`. Or perhaps its a deficiency with higher-kinded types.